# Range of a function, algebraically

Tags: functions

When I tried computing the range of the expression $$ y= \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-3}{x-5} $$ various graphical websites and computational engines indicated that the function $ y $ has a range of $(0,\frac{1}{6}) \cup (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}]$ , this is then obvious to ask if there is a method to compute the range for this function, or functions similar to this one  algebraically, or rather if there exists a better way to compute range of such functions than graphing it.

Comment: Your function is defined at more points than the two intervals you mention.

Comment: The question is a little unclear to me. I assume you consider the real valued function defined on $D=\{x\in \mathbb R \vert\, x\neq 5 \text{ and } -4 \le x\}$ given as
$$
f:D\to \mathbb R,\,x\mapsto \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-3}{x-5}.
$$

And now you want to know what the image $f((0,1/6)\cup (1/6,1/3])$ is, right?

Comment: @Alex I doubt it. I'm pretty sure that the OP confused "domain” and "range"

Comment: @Alex you're right, the function is real

Comment: Aniii, coffeemath's comment refered to your mistaken wording (corrected 1 hour ago by Amogh): "the function y
 is *defined* over the reals for the interval $(0,\frac{1}{6}) \cup (\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{3}]$".

Comment: @AnneBauval my bad, certainly I was mistaken, thanks to Amogh for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is *algebraic* and rigorous *(by equivalences)* proof that the range of your function is indeed $\left(0,\frac16\right) \cup\left(\frac16,\frac13\right].$

An arbitrary real number $y$ is in the range iff
$$\exists x\ne5,\quad(x-5)y+3\ge0\text{ and }\left((x-5)y+3\right)^2=x+4$$
(such a real number $x$ is *de facto* $\ge-4$ since $x+4$ is a square), i.e. (letting $t=x-5$ and simplifying the equation) iff
$$\exists t\ne0,\quad\quad ty+3\ge0\text{ and }y\ne0\text{ and }t=\frac{1-6y}{y^2},$$
i.e. (substituting $t$) iff
$$y\ne\frac16\text{ and }y\ne0\text{ and }\frac{1-3y}y\ge0,$$
i.e.
$$y\ne\frac16\text{ and }0<y\le\frac13.$$

Answer (score 5):

You can simplify the expression using $u=\sqrt{x+4}$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y =
\frac{\sqrt{x+4}-3}{x-5} 
&=
\frac{u-3}{u^{2}-9} \\
&= \frac{1}{u+3}
\phantom{x}
\text{where}
\phantom{x}
u\geq 0, u\neq3
\end{aligned}
$$

From here you can easily see that $y\in\left(0,\frac{1}{3}\right], y\neq\frac{1}{6}$

Comment: This is clever and elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: The domain of the function is $[-4,5)\cup (5,\infty)$. On the two intervals the function is continuous and monotonically decreasing (as seen by differntiation). To find the range you only have to find the value at  $-4$ (which is $\frac 1 3$) and the limiting values at $5$ and $+\infty$ (which are $\frac 1 6$ and $0$ respectively).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \frac{\sqrt{x+4}-3}{x-5}$$
$$\implies 3y-1 = \frac{3\sqrt{x+4}-(x+4)}{x-5}$$
$$\implies3y-1= \frac{(\sqrt{x+4})(3-\sqrt{x+4})}{(\sqrt{x+4})^2-9}$$
$$\implies3y-1= \frac{(\sqrt{x+4})(3-\sqrt{x+4})}{(\sqrt{x+4}-3)(\sqrt{x+4}+3)}$$
$$\implies3y-1= -\frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{\sqrt{x+4}+3}$$
$$\implies y = \frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{\sqrt{x+4}+3}\right)$$

Since $\sqrt{x+4} \ge 0$, $\frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{\sqrt{x+4}+3} \ge 0$

Since $\sqrt{x+4} < \sqrt{x+4}+3$, $\frac{\sqrt{x+4}}{\sqrt{x+4}+3} < 1$

$\implies y \in (0, \frac{1}{3}]$

Since $x \ne 5$, $y \ne \frac{1}{3}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{5+4}}{\sqrt{5+4}+3}\right)$

$\implies y \ne \frac{1}{6}$

Hence, the range of $y$ is $(0, \frac{1}{6}) \cup (\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{3}]$

Comment: Could you please explain what you did on step 2, I'm sorry being just a high school student, I don't really get that.

Comment: I took $\sqrt{x+4}$ out as a common factor in the numerator. Notice how $(x+4)$ can be factorized into $(\sqrt{x+4})(\sqrt{x+4})$

Comment: I realize that, but it'd be appreciated if you explain the initial step, $ \implies 3y-1= \frac{3 \sqrt{x+4}-(x+4)}{x-5} $

Comment: I multiplied $y$ by 3, and then subtracted $1$ from it. Making the denominators like, $1$ can be written as $\frac{x-5}{x-5}$. Then, I combined the like terms in the numerator. $\frac{3\sqrt{x+4}-9-(x-5)}{x-5}=\frac{3\sqrt{x+4}-(x+4)}{x-5}$